# Haskell printing all elements of a list within tuple

Tags: string, list, haskell, tuples

I'm trying to print all elements of the Fans list for a given film title for example all fans of "Avatar" not quite sure how to filter this and display the correct elements as a string. Here is the type definition of the program with some of the test data.

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List

--types
type Title = String
type Director = String
type Year = Int
type Fans = [String]

type Film = (Title, Director, Year, Fans)

type Database = [Film]

testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase = [
 ("Blade Runner", "Ridley Scott", 1982, ["Zoe", "Heidi", "Jo", "Kate", "Emma", "Liz", "Sam", "Olga", "Tim"]),
 ("The Fly", "David Cronenberg", 1986, ["Garry", "Dave", "Zoe", "Kevin", "Emma"]),
 ("Body Of Lies", "Ridley Scott", 2008, ["Bill", "Olga", "Tim", "Zoe", "Paula"]),
 ("Avatar", "James Cameron", 2009, ["Dave", "Amy", "Liz"]),
 ("Titanic", "James Cameron", 1997, ["Zoe", "Emma", "Paula", "Liz", "Olga", "Dave"])]
```

Comment: What if the film cannot be found? For instance `printFans testDatabase "Star Wars"`?

Comment: that is also an issue however could be cleared up  after initial functionality is achieved

Comment: can deal with catching incorrect inputs within the development of the UI

Comment: how should the fans be printed? In what format?

Comment: As a string with comas separating each element

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck, can you make a string from a lit of strings in the format you want?

Comment: So far I have conducted other tasks such as printing all films after a given year and films a certain fan is a fan off I am just unsure about how to output the list and have it be dependant on the title

Answer (score 2):

You're really shooting yourself in the foot by using type synonyms for everything. `data Film = Film Title Director Year Fans` is much better than using a tuple in this case. Defining a separate `Film` data type brings the semantic difference between a `Film` and a tuple of `Title`, `Director`, `Year`, and `Fans` into the type system. This means that you can define instances for it (like `Show` or `Eq`) that will behave in a specific way that is different from what a tuple would give you. It also causes the compiler to reject code that (potentially accidentally) mixes a tuple that happens to have the type `(String,String,Int,[String])` with an actual `Film`. This adds safety, which is one of the main reasons to use Haskell in the first place.

That said, listing the fans only is pretty simple either way:

```
listFans :: Film -> String
-- data way
listFans (Film _ _ _ fans) = intersperse ',' fans
-- tuple way
listFans (_,_,_,fans) = intersperse ',' fans
```

Next, we need a `lookupFilm :: Database -> Title -> Maybe Film` to find the film we want. We need the `Maybe` because the `Film` might not be in the `Database`.

```
lookupFilm :: Database -> Title -> Maybe Film
lookupFilm db t = find (\(Film t' _ _ _) -> t == t') db
```

Note that this doesn't "print" the strings, it just returns them, so you would need `putStrLn . listFans :: Film -> IO ()` to actually output them.

If you always lookup films by their title, you might as well use a `Map Title Film` from [Data.Map](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.10.1/docs/Data-Map.html).

Lastly: be sure you understand how [`find`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/Data.Foldable.html#find) and [`intersperse`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#intersperse) work; `Data.List` is like being given a fish, but you need to learn how to fish for yourself in order to tackle more complex problems as they arise.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback will look into using the data method any way you could elaborate on why this method is preferable